# Sort column based on values in column

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I'm trying to work out a seemingly easy task and, if I had the time and dedication to really get to it, I would probably be able to solve it myself.

However, due to time constraints and lack of thorough VBA and/or Excel knowledge, I am stuck with the following:

An excel spread sheet with 1 column (C in my case) with data. Row 1 contains a header, row 2 as well. Row 3 through 655 contain data with the following format:

```
1.25L Soft Drinks - 7 Up
1.25L Soft Drinks - Coke
1.25L Soft Drinks# - 7 Up
1.25L Soft Drinks# - Coke
```

Basically all the data in column C contains a duplicate, being the only difference the # tag. I would very much like to sort column C in such a way that the products w/o # appear on tab, alphabetically sorted and the products with # appear at the bottom, also alphabetically sorted. A nice to have would be an empty row between the set of data with # and set of data w/o #.

I am pretty sure that similar codes or other methods have been worked out before but after 3 pretty annoying and time-wasting hours searching the internet my boss really doesn't want me to get on with it :( I do however HAVE to sort the data. I would have to this multiple times so I am eagerly looking for VBA code.

Comment: Add a helper column with something like  `=IF(ISERROR(FIND("#",C3)),1,2)`   Sort on that column and then your data in ColC.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a custom [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) on your data by adding a helper column that determines whether the hashmark character exists in the description. Use that as the primary sort key and column C as a secondary sort key.

```
Sub hash_sort()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")    '<~~ set this properly
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count + 1).Offset(1, 0)
                .Columns(.Columns.Count).Cells.Formula = "=isnumber(find(char(35), C2))"
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(.Columns.Count), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Key2:=.Columns(3), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
                .Columns(.Columns.Count).EntireColumn.Delete
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The 'helper' column is immediately deleted once its purpose has been fulfilled.

[image: Custom Sort on Hashmark with helper column]

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, Thanks for the solution!